# Ruby: parsing CSV from ARGF, broken?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a `file.csv`:

```
value1,value2
```

that I convert to JSON using the following command:

```sh
# adding headers on the fly
echo 'key1,key2' |
ruby -rcsv -rjson -e 'puts CSV.new(ARGF,headers:true).map(&:to_hash).to_json' - file.csv
```

The output should be:

```json
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

Which is the case with ruby-2.0 and 2.3, but with ruby-2.7, the output is:

```json
[]
```

Further debugging showed that ruby-2.7 CSV lib doesn't handle ARGF well, it stops the reading after the first *file* in ARGF (stdin in my case).

Are newer Ruby versions also affected by this issue? Is there a more *portable* way to do the same magic?

Comment: Here's the bug report: https://github.com/ruby/csv/issues/228

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this problem.  It seems like the `ARGF` object is behaving the same way in both Ruby 2.5 and Ruby 2.7 though.  Both versions give me this output:

```
$ echo 'key1,key2' | ruby -rcsv -rjson -e 'p ARGF.read; p ARGF.read; p ARGF.read' - file.csv
"key1,key2\n123,345\n"
nil
nil
```

However, there must be something weird about what the CSV library is doing that make your use case stop working.

Anyway, instead of counting on Ruby's ARGF and CSV libraries to concatenate the standard input with `file.csv`, you can just concatenate those two things using your shell instead, and it will work:

```
( echo 'key1,key2'; cat file.csv ) | ruby -rcsv -e 'puts CSV(ARGF,headers:true).map(&:to_hash)'
```

or

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'puts CSV(ARGF,headers:true).map(&:to_hash)' <( echo 'key1,key2'; cat file.csv )
```

Comment: `ARGF.read` does work as expected though: for example `echo 'key1,key2' | ruby -rcsv -rjson -e 'puts CSV.parse(ARGF.read, headers: true).map(&:to_hash).to_json' - file.csv` is working on with ruby-2.7

Comment: Replacing my "_adding a header on the fly_" with a shell construct is a fine workaround. Its more problematic replacing the file arguments: `ruby [...] file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv ...` does **not** work (with `CSV(ARGF)`)

Comment: How about `ruby [...] <( cat file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv )` ?

Comment: By the way, it does seem like you've probably found a bug in Ruby's CSV or ARGF library.  You could report it to the Ruby developers.

Comment: I finished installing ruby-3.0, it doesn't work too... I'll fill a bug report.